# Replace the special character and space from the string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a below string. I need to remove all the special character and space.

```
var Uid = "s/Information Needed1-s84102-p306";
```

I tried the below code.It didn't replace the space from the string.

```
console.log(Uid.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')}")
```

The output is:-    **sInformation Needed1s84102p306**

I want the output as **sInformationNeeded1s84102p306**

Comment: Please clarify if `_` should be removed or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply try using

```
/[\W_]/g
```

- `\W` match any non-word character `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Included `_` if you also want to remove it then

[**Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/jJ2bM6/2)

Answer (score 3):

You can just use:

```
console.log(Uid.replace(/\W+/g, '')}")
```

`\W` will match any non-word character including a space.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yA3gQ3/3)

Comment: you don't actually need the +, right? since you have the g.

Comment: Even if `g` flag `+` is good for efficiency purpose as more than one non-word characters get replaced in one go.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this expression for your case

```
var x = "s/Information Needed1-s84102-p306";
console(x.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, ""));
```

Here is the working [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/em8ngb3x/)

Comment: Interesting, this solution might turn out better if `_` should be removed too.